# Is it safe to connect a 3.3v fan to gpio instead of power?

Tags: gpio, cooling

I have a Raspberry Pi 4B and [a fan](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/YCCFAN-model-YDL3007S05-30mm-3007-dc_60719636399.html). According to the instructions paper of the fan, it should be connected to

- a ground and a 3.3V power
- , or a ground and a 5V power.

So I've used the former setup which uses pins 1 and 6 as marked red in the image below and it's working without any problems for months.

The problem is that generally it is [impossible](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=29309) to control power pins using a software. But I'd like to turn on or off the fan according to the cpu temperature. According to the [documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/), GPIO output is 3.3V or 0V, so it seems the number of voltages are same as the 3.3V power pin.

Questions:

1. Is it possible **and** safe to drive the fan using GPIO pins?
2. If possible, which pins can I use?

Since I'm a very beginner of GPIO and electronics, I'm sorry if the question doesn't make sense.

[image]

<sub>(The image above is an edited version of a image found in [the official documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/).)</sub>

Comment: Perhaps helpful discussion: [Difference between GPIO and 3.3V pin](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=128529)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can not power a fan from a Pi GPIO.

A Pi GPIO can only supply about 16mA at 3V3 which is not enough to power a fan.

Additionally directly connecting a Pi GPIO to any inductive load (DC motor, relay coil etc.) can destroy the GPIO and the Pi.

Comment: So there is no way to control the fan programmatically (as far as I stick to using the fan)? It's a little bit noisy since my room is very silent.

Comment: @ynn You need to use a switch to turn the power on/off for the fan.  The switch can be controlled by a GPIO.  E.g. a transistor is an electronic switch.

Comment: Thanks to your hint, I found many articles explaining it. Thank you :)